# Start Debugging on Visual Studio 19 and Monogame/Xna takes way to long

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2019, monogame

i´m currently working with Visual Studio´19 and Monogame 3.7.1, it works very well, good performance etc. But then from on point to another when i start debugging to test the code, it takes up to 30 secs or more to startup the debugbuild. The Memory in this Timeframe is using about 12-13mb and i have no clue what there is going on. Other Programms/Frameworks are starting debugging in no Time, it´s only with Monogame. Any Ideas how to fix it? Reinstall VS and Monogame will solve the Problem, but it´s not the best solution i guess. :)

Thx a lot.

Comment: Usually the code is building/compiling the moment it starts debugging, so waiting before it starts up is not uncommon. But if your project is new, then waiting 30 seconds is a bit on the long side. Do your PC uses a harddisk or an SSD?

Comment: Hey, i´m using an SSD. Software-Setup is Win 8.1, Visual Studio 19, Monogame 3.7.1. I tried to pause the debugging-process and continue it after 1 min and the program starts immediately? I dont get it^^

Comment: And at this Point, without doing ANYTHING, it works like it never happend before. It runs smooth and startup is about 0.5 to 1 second... And in 2 Weeks it will happen again oO

Comment: How Much memory do you have on your computer? What other tasks are running in the background?  The first compilation after some changes takes longer to run initially. This sounds like an antivirus issue. The AV I have at work locks up a machine for 3 minutes on a new program.